# I want to generate unique alphabetical keys in alphabetical order |angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I want to generate keys in alphabetical order in such a way that it begins with

> aaaaa

then the next would be `aaaab` and after reaching to  `aaaaz` the string should be `aaaba` and then `aaabb` and so on , so that the keys generate properly

My  sample JSON to be created

```
 var keygen={aaaaa,
             aaaab,
             aaaac .........aaaaz,aaaba ....}
```

my javascript

```
$scope.doKeyGen=function(lastValueInJSON)
                {  // Do something 
                   }
```

Comment: what is lastValueInJson

Comment: @JinsPeter whatever be the last value inside the JSON , I meant

Comment: You want a recursive function ?

Comment: do you want to generate the json or sort it?

Comment: @JeanJacques would be good

Comment: generate the JSON @jinsPeter

Comment: @Vibhor please check the answer

Comment: @Vibhor can u gives us a vote too??

Comment: I can vote up only one person at a time @JinsPeter

Comment: You can vote as many as you want. You just cant accept more than one answer.

Comment: @JinsPeter done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you. JS Fiddle is here.

https://jsfiddle.net/3d789okv/7/

Make sure that you the last value you give will be hit.
Otherwise you are going to an infinite loop hell. 
Also you can configure the number of letters in the call to getNext().
But make sure that you set the equal number of letters in the first value and "aaaaa" and the last value "asxas"

```
 String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
        return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
    }

 var json = [];
 function getNext(charCount,lastValue){
    changeIndex = charCount -1;
   var newValue = "";
     while (changeIndex >= 0){
        if(lastValue[changeIndex] !== "z"){
           var changed = lastValue[changeIndex];
           var replacechanged = String.fromCharCode(changed.charCodeAt(0)+1);
           newValue = lastValue.replaceAt(changeIndex,replacechanged)
           for(var j=changeIndex+1; j < charCount; ++j){
              newValue = newValue.replaceAt(j,"a");
           }
           return newValue;
         }
         changeIndex--;
      }
 }

 function createJSON(lastValue){
    if(!json.length){
      //var startPrefix = "aaaaa";
      json.push("aaaaa");
      while(lastValue !== json[json.length-1]){

         json.push(getNext(5,json[json.length-1]));
      }
      console.log(json);
    }
 }

 createJSON("aaabz");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursive function to generate your keys.
I've written some piece of code in this [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/gs6jcuLj/), which generate keys as per your requirement and create JSON too.

**Please note** I assume small case alphabets keys only. and used 3 length string (aaa), You can use 4 length also but performance degrades.

You can change any first key in input in attached fiddle, like `'aay'` then code generate next all possible keys.(aaz, aba,.....,zzz).

Comment: hello @anoop , however I recently received request to make changes and it increments only one element , so basically if i give aaa it will change to aab and pushes just aab to the JSON , i tried editing your jsfiddle but couldnt , can u help plz ?

Comment: @Vibhor: don't know much about your new requirement, but ofcourse you can push as soon as new key gets created, See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phygg4ah/) , I've jus logged the json and comment other keys generation code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
function getNextKey(lastKeyCode, changeIndex)
{
  var charCodes = [];
  if( changeIndex == undefined )
      changeIndex = lastKeyCode.length - 1;


  if(changeIndex - 1 > -1 && lastKeyCode.charCodeAt(changeIndex) == 122 )
  {
     lastKeyCode = getNextKey(lastKeyCode, changeIndex - 1);
  }

  lastKeyCode.split('').forEach(function(e){charCodes.push(e.charCodeAt())});
  charCodes[changeIndex] = 97 + (charCodes[changeIndex] - 96 ) % 26;

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(0, charCodes);
}

  //-------------------EDIT ( GENERATE KEYS LIKE THIS )------------
function generateKeys(lastKey)
{
  var json = [];
  var nextKey = new Array(lastKey.length + 1 ).join('a');
  json.push(nextKey);

  while( nextKey != lastKey )
  {
    json.push( (nextKey = getNextKey(nextKey)) )
  }

  return json;
}
  //---------------------------Example----------------------------


var last = 'test';
console.log('Last Key : '+last+' | Generated key length : '+generateKeys(last).length);
```

Comment: If you change the correct answer because of generation of keys i edited the answer @Vibhor